# How to read continuously updating log file & match particular pattern in perl script

Tags: perl, file-handling

I want to read continuously updating log file. If I get particular pattern then I should be able to send a mail which I  am able to do.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line;
my $to = 'abc@abc.com';
my $from = 'xyz@abc.com';
my $subject = 'Connection Pool Issue';
my $message = 'There is connection pool issue. Please check Logs for more details';

open my $fh, '<', 'error.txt';
my @file = <$fh>;
close $fh;

foreach my $line (@file) {


 if ($line =~ /The connection is closed./) 

 { 

    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    print MAIL "To: $to\n";
    print MAIL "From: $from\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
    # Email Body
    print MAIL $message;

    close(MAIL);
    print "Email Sent Successfully\n";

    last;
  }
}
```

I don't want to read file from file handler 0 that means from starting position.

I expect to read a file from current file handler position.
It should not include already read lines.

Please suggest.
Thank you

Comment: Tip: Don't needless use of global vars! Use `open(my $MAIL, ...)` instead of `open(MAIL, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tail).

```
use File::Tail qw( );

my $tail = File::Tail->new( name => $qfn );
while (defined( my $line = $tail->read() )) {
   if ($line =~ /The connection is closed\./) {
      ...
   }
}
```

If you need the preceding lines,

```
use File::Tail qw( );

my $tail = File::Tail->new( name => $qfn );
my @buf;
while (defined( my $line = $tail->read() )) {
   push @buf, $line;
   if ($line =~ /The connection is closed\./) {
      ...
      @buf = ();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem 2 different ways.

With no modules you can do something like:

```
-Check if line count file exists and read into variable
-loop through file line by line, increment counter
-if $loop_line_count < $line_count_previous_run : skip
-if $total_line_count < $line_count_previous_run : reset file count to 0
-write total_line_count to file
```

With File::Tail

```
my $file=File::Tail->new( name=>"$log_file",internal=>10, maxinterval=>30, adjustafter=>5);

while (defined(my $line=$file->read)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The first approach hammers the CPU and file system. It also doesn't handle log rotations.

Comment: It does handle log rotations. it will reset a log file counter if the total file count is less than the previous run and reset the counter to 0. Also each File::Tail reads the entire file as well CPU/Disk usage will be basically the same.

Comment: That's not true. F::T has delays built in to avoid this specifically and it does a far better job at detecting log rotations than you do. Your method doesn't always work. (It's weird that you make this claim because your F::T example shows you overriding the default values used by the mechanisms that address both of these issues!!!)

Comment: interval is default, max interval is halved (60 -> 30) and adjust after is also halved ( 10-> 5) that's hardly changing anything rather then my scripts response time to new lines. My use case was for a smile sized log file that is rotated daily.

Comment: What are you trying to demonstrate by mentioning that? I don't see your point.